# Where is -32768 coming from?

Tags: assembly, load, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture, lc3

This is LC3 Assembly code I am working with

```
.ORIG x3000
LOOP LDI R0, KBSR 
BRzp LOOP
```

From [LC3 Assembly](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~milom/cse240-Fall05/handouts/Ch05.pdf), I know that LDI is a load indirect addressing mode, meaning it read in an address stored at an location and then read the value at that location

From  [Lc3 Keyboard](https://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmpe012/Summer08/notes/10_LC3_IO_markup.pdf), I know that KBSR is the keyboard status register, which is one when keyboard has received a new character.

Here is my test run in Lc3 simulator? I entered the character 'a' [image]

After executing LDI R0, KBSR, register 0 stores a value of -32768.

Does anyone know, based off my definitions for ldi and KBSR where this number is coming from? I was expecting something like 1 to be stored because the keyboard has received a new character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In KBSR (keyboard status register) bit 15 is set when a key is read, so you get `0b1000_0000_0000_0000` (or `0x8000`) ... which - interpreted as a 2's complemented negative number - happens to be -32768 decimal.